# How do I fix broken packages hindering updates in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: package-management, dependencies, gnome-terminal, terminator

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop and tried to install Terminator. I am getting broken packages error when I run:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

The error message comes from the `gstreamer1.0` and `libgstreamer` packages.

I've tried to run:

```
sudo apt-get install -f && sudo apt-get update
```

but all in vain.

Can someone help me fix this?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the exact output from the commands you try.

Comment: 'Throw errors' is too vague. Show exactly what happens. The -f should not be needed, don't get in the force habit. I suggest you "apt-get install --reinstall gstreamer1.0", and the other one too to make sure they are whole and good.  Then tell us where you are getting Terminator, because In Ubuntu 16.04, I just ran "apt-get install Terminator" and found nothing.  This makes me suspect you have a package built on different repo, and you don't fix that kind of problem with force.

Answer (score 0):

Reboot your system and stop while booting into OS and choose your in this way: depackaging option depckg and this leads to update your broken packages.

just restart your system and start pressing Alt+F4(may be vary from os to os).

Comment: Can ypu rewrite your answer to give step by step directions? It may be confusing to a new user,

Answer (score 0):

Your error message is resulting from GStreamer. After a fresh installation of Ubuntu 16.04 you need to install three main packages before building GStreamer. Follow [this](https://developer.ridgerun.com/wiki/index.php?title=GStreamer_build_on_Ubuntu_16.04) link to solve the problem resulting from GStreamer.

If you probably get an error on running the first command, try to fix broken packages first using:

`sudo apt-get update –fix-missing && sudo dpkg –configure -a && sudo apt-get install -f && sudo fuser -vki /var/lib/dpkg/lock && sudo dpkg –configure -a`

Retry the solution in the above pinned link.

Success!